# SocialEngine module with custom routes

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, routes, socialengine

I'm developing a module for the SocialEngine package and I'd like to be able to specify multiple custom routes.

Currently I'm editing the Bootstrap.php file found in the directory of my module with the following;

```
class Courses_Bootstrap extends Engine_Application_Bootstrap_Abstract
{
    protected function _initRouter(){
        $fc = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
        $router = $fc->getRouter();
        $router->addRoute('courses', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/activity/:activity_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'index','action' => 'activity')));
        $router->addRoute('courses', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/course/edit/:course_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course','action' => 'edit')));
        $router->addRoute('courses', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/course/create/:course_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course','action' => 'create')));

        return $router;
    }

}
```

However it would seem that when I specify more then 1 route all routes stop passing in the custom variable (course_id or activity_id)

I'm retrieving the variable as follows;

```
$course_id = $this->getRequest()->getParam("course_id");
```

I've taken the approach from here;
http://tjgamble.com/2011/04/adding-custom-routes-to-your-socialengine-4-modules/

Many thanks,

Andy

Comment: How about adding them in manifest.php?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to give them different names:

```
    $router->addRoute('courses_activitiy', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/activity/:activity_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'index','action' => 'activity')));
    $router->addRoute('courses_course', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/course/edit/:course_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course','action' => 'edit')));
    $router->addRoute('courses_create', new Zend_Controller_Router_Route('courses/course/create/:course_id', array('module' => 'courses', 'controller' => 'course','action' => 'create')));
```

Comment: same answer would apply - they need different `names` in the config array.